# Svelte Object property bindings

Tags: svelte

I have a writable obj defined in my stores.js as

```js
export const opts = writable({});
```

in one of my components, I set

```js
$opts = {"key1": 0, ...};
```

In one of my forms,

I have used radio button with the following bindings

```
<input type="radio" bind:group={$opts.key1} value={0}/>
```

The radio button shows the initial default value that I set. But if I set it somewhere in the code based on user input, to another value doing $opts.key1 = 1, I was expecting that my form will render that. But it doesnt selects any of the radio button in the group.

it looks that I am missing something in my understanding how it works. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: My mistake. There was a bug in my code, I was setting the $opts.key1 as "0" (string) and my value was set to {0}. Setting either of them to match with the value of the other resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me:

```html
<!-- App.svelte -->
<script>
    import { opts } from './store.js';
    
    function handleClick() {
        $opts.key1 = 1;
    }
</script>

<p>
    Value of $opts.key1: {$opts.key1}
</p>

<label><input type="radio" bind:group={$opts.key1} value={0}> 0</label>
<label><input type="radio" bind:group={$opts.key1} value={1}> 1</label>

<button on:click={handleClick}>Update $opts.key1</button>
```

```js
// store.js
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

export const opts = writable({"key1": 0, "otherfield": "whatever" });
```

When I click the button, the `opts` store is updated and the second radio button is selected.

Comment: it doesnt work for me as I dont have any click event to update the $opts.key1. I am updating it by loading an input file which sets the $opts = to a new value. But my form do not get rendered. None of the radio buttons are selected. The deafult I set in onMount shows up correctly. However, when I did "$: console.log($opts.key1);", it did shows that it has been sett to correct value.